# NLP Classification on a dataset

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I am trying to learned NLP. I understand the basic concepts from Text Preprocessing to td-idf, and Word Embedding. How do I apply this learning? I have a Data set with two columns: Answer and Gender. I want to use NLP to transform the Answer column to vectors and then use supervised machine learning to train a model that predict where a certain type of answer was given by male or a female.
I dont know how to process after I Pre_processed the text.

Comment: SO is for programming questions so your question is likely to be closed. If you make your question more specific you could ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. Short answer: the next step is supervised machine learning, more precisely classification in this case. I'd suggest starting with a simple algorithm such as Naive Bayes or decision trees. [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) is one of the standard libraries nowadays. You''ll find plenty of tutorials online, search for "text classification" and your favourite language or library.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could encode your label into numeric. Then, you tokenize the answer text using TF-IDF. Tokenization can be used to represent the text in a vector that computer understands. But, non-contextual word representation would not help representing the lexical relation between words. So, I would suggest you use contextual embedding, like BERT.

After you tokenize your text, then you feed those vector and label into whatever classifier you build. For example, you could try using SVM, BiLSTM, or you could just feed them to BERT!

The accuracy, or whatever metrics you hope to achieve will be based on how you construct your model's architecture, what choice of tokenization you choose, and most importantly how representative is your data.

Happy exploring!

Answer (score 0):

You can download datasets which are available in Matlab format.

All of them are divided into train and test datasets.

[check my GitHub](https://github.com/AIAML/Datasets_TextCategorization)